# Passing a multidimensional array as a literal to a method call in Java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, variadic-functions

I have written two convenience methods for accessing a more complex method for parameterized sql queries/executes.

The first one is:

```
public int sqlExecute(String sql, String... parameters)
```

which i can call like

```
sqlExecute("exec blah ?, ?, ?", "param1", "param2", "param3");
```

The second one is defined as:

```
public int sqlExecute(String sql, String[]... parameters)
```

which should be called with an array[2][whatever size] that holds in the first column the type (more precisely its the "table.column" of a field which provides the type... I have to implement it this way) and the second the value of the parameter to use.

A call like

```
sqlExecute("exec blah ?, ?", {"account.name", "foo"}, {"account.region", "bar"});
```

results in "Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens" (using Eclipse Luna).
Isn't that correct syntax?

What I wish to accomplish is that I don't have to define some variable which holds the array, but rather call the method with an array literal like I can with method #1.
Is there another way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should call it like

```
sqlExecute("exec blah ?, ?", 
    new String[] {"account.name", "foo"}, 
    new String[] {"account.region", "bar"});
```

You can add a helper method to make this shorter:

```
public static String[] arr(String... args) {
    return args;
}

sqlExecute("exec blah ?, ?", 
    arr("account.name", "foo"), 
    arr("account.region", "bar"));
```

Comment: Well,... that's rather unfortunate that one has to do so "much" extra code (yeah I am lazy :) ). Is there any reason why the "new String[]" before can't be skipped (if they would implement it into the language)? Nevertheless thank you for your answer.

Comment: Edited the answer. Probably you will like this version more.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use

```
sqlExecute("exec blah ?, ?",
        new String[] {"account.name", "foo"},
        new String[] {"account.region", "bar"});
```